# How to store item from listView to string in C#?

Tags: c#, listview

I have a file path stored in an item in a listView (it's the only item in the listView) and I need to be able to read its text and store it into a string so that I can use it else where in my code.

More specifically, I need to make it so that when I press a button, it will read the text from the item generated in the listView and store it to a string.

I have tried a few solutions online but none of them seem to work.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you whatever you have tried and tell us what exact issue you are facing with that? `none of them seem to work.` is not a problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem("File path"));
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var itemvalue = listView1.Items[0].Text;
    }
}
```

This should help you getting the item value.